# Is there a way to count occurrence of values of multiple column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say I have a table storing survey result, and the syntax looks something like this:

```
id | q1 | ..... | q30 | created_at
```

`created_at` is a timestamp column and all others are integers fields.

Now I want to have a result of the survey according to month. To do that for one question, I have:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) as year, MONTH(created_at) as month, q1, count(*) as occurrence
  FROM survey_table
 GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at), q1
```

The return will be something like:

```
year | month| q1 | occurence
2016 | 11   | 1  | 10
2016 | 11   | 2  | 15
2016 | 11   | 3  | 2
2016 | 10   | 1  | 12
2016 | 10   | 2  | 2
2016 | 10   | 3  | 50
```

The data will be passed to my PHP script for further calculation and finally some data-display.

To do calculation on 30 columns, one way is to perform this query 30 times for different question. I am wondering if there is a way to do that in single query so that the output will be something like this:

```
year | month| q1_1 | q1_2 | q1_3 | q2_1 | q2_2 | q2_3 | ... | q30_1 | q30_2 | q30_3
2016 | 11   | 10   | 15   | 2    | 2    | 20   | 5    | ... | 5     | 15    | 7    
2016 | 10   | 12   | 2    | 50   | 25   | 27   | 12   | ... | 20    | 24    | 20
```

Is there a way to do this in one query? If yes, is this performance better?

Comment: Google -> SQL Pivoting

Comment: Google if you like, but issues of data display are generally best resolved in application level code (assuming that's available) - oh, and NORMALISE your design.

Answer (score 2):

This is how your query would look:

```
select 
  year(created_at) as year, 
  month(created_at) as month, 
  count(q1 = 1) as q1_1,
  count(q1 = 1) as q1_2,
  count(q1 = 1) as q1_3,
  count(q1 = 2) as q2_1,
  ...
  count(q30 = 3) as q30_3
from survey_table
group by year(created_at), month(created_at);
```

It seems, however, it would be much better to change your table design:

```
q_type | q_value |created_at
-------+---------+----------
1      | 1       | 2016-10-05
2      | 3       | 2016-10-05
3      | 1       | 2016-10-05
4      | 2       | 2016-10-05
...
30     | 1       | 2016-10-05
...
29     | 1       | 2016-10-08
30     | 2       | 2016-10-08
```

And your query would simply be:

```
select 
  year(created_at) as year, 
  month(created_at) as month, 
  q_type,
  q_value,
  count(*)
from survey_table
group by year(created_at), month(created_at), q_type, q_value;
```

You'd do the formatting, i.e. putting the data in a grid, in PHP. This is more flexible, as your query doesn't have to know any longer how many q types and how many q values exist.

Comment: True that this table design will be easier for this operation, but it makes it hard to take all results from a single survey. Also, in the actual application, there are other types of question that the answer is not integer, so this design is not possible.

Comment: Okay, then use the first query. However, you would need to know all possible q values (1 to 3 in your example) beforehand. Or build the query dynamically. Or really write 30 queries and combine them into a single query with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @cytsunny This makes EVERYTHING easier. you just might need to tweak the design very, very slightly, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `UNION ALL` query I mentioned in a comment to my other answer. You don't have to know what q values exist when writing the query, and due to `UNION ALL` it's just one query that gets executed (so as to avoid unnecessary round trips).

It is still not a speeding fast query due to the current table design.

```
select year(created_at) as year, month(created_at) as month, 'Q1', q1, count(*) as cnt
from survey_table
group by year(created_at), month(created_at), q1
UNION ALL
select year(created_at) as year, month(created_at) as month, 'Q2', q2, count(*) as cnt
from survey_table
group by year(created_at), month(created_at), q2
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
select year(created_at) as year, month(created_at) as month, 'Q30', q30, count(*) as cnt
from survey_table
group by year(created_at), month(created_at), q30;
```